# Get parent text of input element

Tags: jquery

I'd like to capture all inputs and get their labels. So I'd like to get Customer ID, Customer Name and Birthday in this particular case.

```
<div id="group1">
    <div class="col-4 last-col">
        Customer ID:<br />
        <input name="tbCustomerId" id="tbCustomerId" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 last-col">
        Customer Name:<br />
        <input name="tbCustomerName" id="tbCustomerName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 last-col">
        Birthday:<br />
        <input name="tbCustomerBirthdayDate" id="tbCustomerBirthdayDate" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var inputs = $(':input', '#group1');
        $.each(inputs, function (key, value) {
            //I tried value.parent().text() but no luck.
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: And you received an error on `.parent()` or `.text()` correct? Why not include that in your question? The problem here is that `value` isn't a jQuery object and therefore doesn't have jQuery methods.

Comment: I didn't have the console up to see it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `value` to jQuery object

```
$(function () {
  var inputs = $(':input', '#group1');
  $.each(inputs, function (key, value) {
    $(value).parent().text(); // or $(this) 
  })
})
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/kewamu/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your jquery selector is correctly selecting the input elements? Try this

```
$('#group1 input').each(function(){ console.log($(this).parent().text());});
```